# Pasar valores de select por POST a controlador CodeIgniter

Tags: php, array, codeigniter, formularios, post

Verán quiero obtener el valor de las opciones elegidas en los `select`, a través de `POST`, ¿tengo que hacer un `array` con los valores seleccionados?, intenté hacer algo pero no obtuve
Vista del formulario

```
<?php if(!empty($GenerarExamen)){
                foreach ($GenerarExamen as $ge) {
                    if($ge->idTipoPreg=='1'){ ?>
        <form action="<?=base_url()?>index.php/examenEmp/Result/<?=$ge->idExamen?>/<?=$cveEmpleado?>/<?=$ge->idSolicitud?>" method="POST" class="form">
                    <fieldset>
                    <input type="hidden" name="idPregunta" value="<?=$ge->idPregunta?>">
                        <legend><?=$ge->pregunta?></legend>
                        <select name="pregunta" class="form-control" required="target"  >
                        <option value="">Selecciona una respuesta</option>
                        <?php 
                        $this->load->model('examenEmp_model');
                        $idPreg=$ge->idPregunta;
                        $Resp= $this->examenEmp_model->respuesta($idPreg);
                        if(!empty($Resp)){
                            foreach ($Resp as $t) {
                                ?>
                                    <option value="<?=$t->inciso?>"><?=$t->respuesta?></option> 
                                <?php } 
                            }?>
                            </select>
                        </fieldset>
                        <br>

                        <?php }elseif ($ge->idTipoPreg=='2') {?>
                        <fielset>
                            <input type="hidden" name="idPregunta" value="<?=$ge->idPregunta?>">
                            <br>
                            <label><?=$ge->pregunta?></label>
                            <br>
                            <textarea required="target" placeholder="Escribe tu respuesta..." class="form-control"></textarea>
                        </fieldset>
                        <?php
                    }
                }
            }

            ?>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-large">Aceptar</button>
        </form>
```

Y aquí el código de mi controlador, funciona si sólo lo hago con una pregunta pero no sé cómo hacerlo con más de una. ¿podrían ayudarme? :)

```
   <?php  public function Result($idExamen,$cveEmpleado, $idSolicitud) {
     $valor=$this->input->POST('valor');
     $r=$this->input->POST('incisoCto');
     $incisoS=$this->input->POST('pregunta');
     if ($incisoS==$r) {
     $this->examenEmp_model->agregarR($valor,$idSolicitud);
     }
     else{
      echo "<script>
     alert('No se genero examen');
     </script>" ;
      }
      $this->data['results'] = $this->examenEmp_model->resultTeorico($idSolicitud);
      $this->load->view('result_display', $this->data);
      }?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

He aquí la respuesta por si a alguien le interesa.

Sólo necesitaba arreglar un pequeño detalle y crear un for para obtener los valores en el controlador

```
public function Result($idExamen,$cveEmpleado, $idSolicitud)
 {
  $sum = 0;
 for($i=0; $i<count($this->input->post("preguntaM[]")); $i++)
 {
  $valor[$i]=$this->input->post("valor[".$i."]");
  $r[$i]=$this->input->post("incisoCto[".$i."]");
  $incisoS[$i]=$this->input->post("preguntaM[".$i."]");
  if ($incisoS[$i]==$r[$i]) {
  $sum += $valor[$i];
   }
  }
```

Y agregar corchetes en la vista.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-xs-12" align="center">
        <h2>Exámenes a realizar</h2>
        <?php if(!empty($GenerarExamen)){
            foreach ($GenerarExamen as $ge) {
                if($ge->idTipoPreg=='1'){ ?>
                <form action="<?=base_url()?>index.php/examenEmp/Result/<?=$ge->idExamen?>/<?=$cveEmpleado?>/<?=$ge->idSolicitud?>" method="POST" class="form">
                    <fieldset>
                        <input type="hidden" name="idPregunta" value="<?=$ge->idPregunta?>">
                        <legend><?=$ge->pregunta?></legend>
                        <input type="hidden" name="incisoCto[]" value="<?=$ge->incisoCto?>">
                        <input type="hidden" name="valor[]" value="<?=$ge->valor?>">
                        <select name="preguntaM[]" class="form-control" required="target"  >
                            <option value="">Selecciona una respuesta</option>
                            <?php 
                            $this->load->model('examenEmp_model');
                            $idPreg=$ge->idPregunta;
                            $Resp= $this->examenEmp_model->respuesta($idPreg);
                            if(!empty($Resp)){
                                foreach ($Resp as $t) {
                                    ?>
                                    <option value="<?=$t->inciso?>"><?=$t->respuesta?></option> 
                                    <?php } 
                                }?>
                            </select>
                        </fieldset>
                        <br>

                        <?php }elseif ($ge->idTipoPreg=='2') {?>
                        <fielset>
                            <input type="hidden" name="idPregunta" value="<?=$ge->idPregunta?>">
                            <br>
                            <label><?=$ge->pregunta?></label>
                            <br>
                            <textarea name="preguntaA" required="target" placeholder="Escribe tu respuesta..." class="form-control"></textarea>
                        </fieldset>
                        <?php
                    }
                }
            }

            ?>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-large">Aceptar</button>
        </form>
    </div>
```